# View for ListViewItem is not released

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

Reactiveui is used to bind ReadOnlyObservableCollection  to ItemsSource and add elements to the collection.
The collection has a maximum value and will be deleted accordingly, but the automatically generated view is not released.

The same processing was performed using a ViewModel that has no dependency, but the View was not released.

```cs
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterViewsForViewModels(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
        }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewBase : ReactiveWindow<MainWindowViewModel>
    {
    }

    public partial class MainWindowView : MainWindowViewBase
    {
        public MainWindowView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

            this.WhenActivated(d =>
            {
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
                    vm => vm.Collection,
                    v => v.listBox.ItemsSource)
                    .DisposeWith(d);
            });
        }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<StringViewModel> _collection;
        public ReadOnlyCollection<StringViewModel> Collection => _collection;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10), RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
                .Select(x => new StringViewModel(x.ToString()))
                .ToObservableChangeSet(limitSizeTo: 300)
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .Bind(out _collection)
                .DisposeMany()
                .Subscribe();
        }
    }

    public class StringViewBase : ReactiveUserControl<StringViewModel>
    {
    }

    public partial class StringView : StringViewBase
    {
        public StringView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel)
                .Where(x => x != null)
                .Do(Asign)
                .Subscribe();
        }

        private void Asign(StringViewModel vm)
        {
            _textBlock.Text = vm.Value;
        }
    }

    public class StringViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public StringViewModel(string value)
        {
            Value = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        }

        public string Value { get; }
    }
```

Comment: What UI framework are you using? You haven't listed any. Eg winforms, wpf, xamarin forms

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
WPF is used for UI framework.
Only ListLiew for MainWindowsView, TextBlock only for StringView